# Wait for the query api to return before looping chain async await

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

The problem was I was looping for a array that will be query in a firebase database, instead of waiting for that query to return it will continue to loop even if the return promise is not executed.

Code below executes like this , if a user enters it checks if it is existing, if existing it will query to the real time database to get a specific "data" saved from signing up.

Problem is it will not wait for the query in the real time database, it will immediately loop then executes the query which is wrong. I know that query in firebase returns a function but how do I chain it? Or is there any way to do it easily? Thanks btw

```
loginIdentification = ['citizen','bfp','ndrmmc','pnp','rta'];

  loginAuthentication(email:any,password:any){
    this.loginFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(async authData =>{
      if(authData.uid){
        for (var counter = 0; counter < this.loginIdentification.length; counter++) {
          console.log('counter');
          await this.searchuser(counter,authData.uid);
        }
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(authData.uid));
    }).catch(function (error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log("error code : " + errorCode + " errorMessage : " + errorMessage);
      });
  }

  searchuser(counter,userid){
    var that = this;
      if(counter == 0){
          that.loginFiredatabase.ref('users/' + that.loginIdentification[counter] + '/' + userid).on('value',async function (snapshot) {
            await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot));
              return resolve();
            }
            else{
              return reject();
            }
            });
          });
      }
      else {
          that.loginFiredatabase.ref('users/' + that.loginIdentification[counter] + '/' + userid).on('value',async function (snapshot) {
            await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              if(snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot));
                return resolve();
              }
              else {
                return reject();
              }
          });
    });
      }
  }
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use recursion for this

Comment: @user184994 what do you mean? can you share?